# Connection refused during cloning

Tags: github, devops, cloning

I have github installed in my laptop and I am connected to another repository however,anytime I try to clone any of the repository i receive a message “Connection refused”

Comment: Could you please clarify what do you mean by 'I am connected to another repository'? And it would help if you could include the entire `Connection refused` error string.

Comment: Error message: Cloning into ‘c:\Github\… fatal: unable to access ‘https://GitHub.com/verify333/…’ failed to connect to (ip address) (port number): connection refused

Comment: Could you please confirm if the repo is public or private? Also, what git authentication method are you using?

Comment: Private repo and SSH  authentication

Comment: Recently, I was facing similar kind of an issue. I had to generate a GitHub PAT (Personal Access Token) and use it in CLI to use git operations. You could look into PAT more. Hopefully, that may solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you daishin , I’ll do that